# Create virtual display output device or new X display for recording fullscreen desktop application

Tags: x11, display, window-manager, xrandr, recording

I'd like to create a virtual display which emulates a hardware monitor. For example, I'd like to be able to move application windows to this "monitor", record on the "monitor", etc. Is this possible? It would be equally OK if I had a new X display which can do this, or any other method where I can record the output of an application placed on the "monitor" in full screen, without having the application show up on my physical monitor(s), or just having them take up minimal space on my existing physical monitor(s) (e.g. a little picture-in-picture window that allows e.g. Kazam or other desktop recording software to record the app in it in fullscreen 1920x1080 would be totally fine).

Basically, I have several applications (which run autonomously) that I'd like to record in full screen, but I only have a limited number of hardware displays to do this. Sometimes I have to record like three at a time, and I only have two hardware monitors. And I usually use both hardware monitors for work, so I don't even want to use one for recording, tbh! I guess I could buy three extra monitors, but I was hoping to avoid that.

If it matters, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, but I figured the solution would not depend on the distro. An analogous task is creating a virtual audio device, so that audio streams can be redirected to various virtual audio devices. I guess one way to conceptualize this problem is to achieve the same thing, but with display devices instead of audio devices.

I don't know a lot about the X Window System, X11, xrandr, window managers, virtual displays, picture in picture, etc., so apologies if this is a question with an obvious answer.

Comment: Look for "virtual frame buffer", `Xvfb`, the `xf86-video-dummy` driver. They basically create an "invisible" (and very fast) Xorg display.

Comment: @user414777 thank you very much!